# Send the JWT header from MVC To Api controller

Tags: asp.net-core, session, jwt, httpclient, asp.net-core-webapi

I have web API generate JWT after login and post a new reservation and it works in Postman, now in MVC to consume web API using HttpClient, I can not send the authorized header with the session to api controller and validate it:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateReservation(ReservationViewModel reservation, string returnUrl)
    {
        HttpClient client = _guestApi.Initial();
        var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);

        // Authorization header
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",
            HttpContext.Session.GetString("token"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("/api/Reservation/CreateReservation", null).Result;
        string stringData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Unauthorized");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Sucess", "Successful Reservation Will Contact you Soon");
          
        }
        return View();
```

Api controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("CreateReservation")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Reservation([FromBody] Reservation reservation )

    { 
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest("Not a vailable");
       
        // Create a new Reservation
        reservation = new Reservation()
         {
            GuestName = reservation.GuestName,
            GuestsNumber = reservation.GuestsNumber,
            Menu = reservation.Menu,
            Notes = reservation.Notes,
        };
        _context.Reservations.Add(reservation);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

         return CreatedAtAction("GetReservation", new { id = reservation.Id }, reservation);
      
    }
```

How I can send the JWT header from MVC To Api controller and validate it ?

Answer (score 0):

> It is return error :No overload for method 'PostAsync' takes 1 arguments

From your code,you do not pass any request body or form data,so just change like below:

```
HttpResponseMessage response =await client.PostAsync("YourRequestUrl", null);
```

Comment: Update the question

Comment: It's another question now..I have resolved your previous issue.Please post a new thread and share more details about how and which project did you set the session for token.It seems your api project need token to validate.You set session for it  but if you want to get the session in mvc project,it is impossible.Only if you generate the token and save to the database and the mvc project could get it from the database.